# How to rewrite external links (redirect to an Exit Page) with Apache mod_rewrite or RewriteCond?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I honestly spent hours trying to find a solution (and I'm normally good searching for solutions), but I seem to have an unique problem.

Let's assume that my **current** URL is `http://www.something.com`

I want to change all external links within webpages like the ones below...

```
1. <a href="http://other.something.com">other</a>
2. <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

... to this:

1. <a href="**http://www.something.com/redirect.htm?**`http://other.something.com`">other</a>
2. <a href="**http://www.something.com/redirect.htm?**`http://www.google.com`">google</a>

I do NOT have PHP or ASP. Let's assume that my website is static HTML only. Is there a workable Apache URL rewrite solution?

Thank you

Comment: Apache does not alter page content, `mod_rewrite` is for incoming URLs only.

Comment: Have you considered JavaScript?

Comment: @clmarquart: That would still require alteration to the page content.  If he can do that, he could probably rewrite all the URLs by hand.  Though of course if there are many, it would be preferable with code.

Comment: I can't rewrite all URLs by hand because it's a massive website (over 1,000 pages) and people contribute to it using Macromedia Contribute. That means they can't easily code in external URLs by hand. I know, a CMS is better, but we're still limited to static HTML. I'll try some of the answers on this page and then vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/). Quote from [config guide](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/config.html):

> Syntax: ProxyHTMLURLMap from-pattern
>   to-pattern [flags] [cond]
>
> This is the key directive for
>   rewriting HTML links. When parsing a
>   document, whenever a link target
>   matches from-pattern, the matching
>   portion will be rewritten to
>   to-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

[mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html) might be an alternative.

- On the minus side, it is an unsophisticated regexp filter with [all its](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) [drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).
- On the plus side, it is included in the default apache distribution and *might* be just enough to resolve your problem.

  ```
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
  Substitute s|<a([^>]*)href="http(.?)://(.*)"([^>]*)>|<a $1 href="http://www.something.com?redirect=http$2://$3" $4>|i
  ```

**Edit**

If your site is indeed a set of static html pages, why not do an off-line transformation of them using a proper HTML [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) tool?