# Match External URLs mod_substitute

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to use mod_substitute in .htaccess to match any external URLs that do not match the current domain, and redirect them to a specific page within the website:

```
AddOutputFilterByType INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
Substitute "s|(<a\s[^>]*)href=\"http(.?)://([^/]+)(?<!www\.mywebsite\.dev)/[^\"]*\"|$1href=\"http://www.mywebsite.dev/exit/?redirect=http$2://$3\"|i"
```

It ends up changing my links to this:

```
www.mywebsite.dev/exit/?redirect=www.mywebsite.dev
```

The closest I came in searching is this: [How to rewrite external links (redirect to an Exit Page) with Apache mod_rewrite or RewriteCond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872956/how-to-rewrite-external-links-redirect-to-an-exit-page-with-apache-mod-rewrite) but the example regex creates a server error in .htaccess.

Comment: whats the desired output? What's the input?

Comment: So for example, http://bob.com doesn't match the current domain (mywebsite.com), so it should do: http://mywebsite.com/exit/?redirect=http://bob.com. I've got it replacing URLs in the output, it just doesn't append the domain it's redirecting correctly.